# Asterisk codec G.711.1

Tags: asterisk, voip

I am playing around with Asterisk and using different codec. 
Does anybody know if it is possible to use the codec "G.711.1" within Asterisk?

If so; what would be the best way to install or activate it.

Thanks you,

Wesley Schravendijk

Answer (score 0):

At current moment asterisk support g711a/u(alaw/ulaw) only

If you need wideband codec, use g722(also supported).

You also can use wideband version of speex codec.